# jQuery .submit() is not triggering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I tried on, click, live, submit and it doesn't work properly for my mail submit form. It's like 50% of time it works, 50% it does not.
Here is my code:

Contact.html:

```
<div id="contact">
    <h2>Let keep in touch</h2>
    <form id="mail-form" name="contactform" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
        <input class="contact-form" type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name"><br>
        <input class="contact-form" type="text" name="mail" maxlength="80" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <textarea class="mail-content" name="content" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea><br><br>
        <center><input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send your message"></center>
    </form>
</div>
<div id='thankyou'>Thank you for contacting me. I'll reply as soon as possible.</div>
```

javascript file:

```
$("#mail-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    $.post("send_form_email.php", $("#mail-form").serialize(), function(data) {
        showThankYou();
    });
});

function showThankYou() {
    $contact = $("#contact");
    $thankyou = $("#thankyou");
    $contact.fadeOut(800, function() {
        $thankyou.fadeIn(800);
    });   
}
```

Most of time when i tried to submit, browser was redirected to the blank send_form_email.php. When i pressed the back button, sometimes the submit form works. 
Also, I added alert() into both submit and jquery post functions, and they weren't fired.
Could someone please explain why this is occurring, thank you in advance.

Btw, my website form url is: http://dkonayuki.net/contact.html

And all the emails were sent properly. But browser (chrome) stuck at the blank php page.

The problem is definitely related to my page transition (using ajax). But I have no idea how to fix it without commenting out those code. Here is my transition code:

```
$("nav").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pagename = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // great html5 stuff, change url without reloading entire page
    history.pushState(pagename, "dkonayuki", pagename);

    $mainContent
            .fadeOut(400, function() {
                // and great ajax also
                $mainContent.hide().load(pagename + " #main > *", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(800);
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href='"+ pagename +"']").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript wrapped in a `$(function () { })` so that it executes on DOM-ready?

Comment: are you providing correct path of send_form_email.php?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to wrap the call to `showThankYou()` in an anonymous function, you can say `$.post("send_form_email.php", $("#mail-form").serialize(), showThankYou);`.

Comment: @meagar Yes, i wrap my script in $(document).ready(function() { }

Comment: @urfusion: Yes, that path is correct, because it works sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I finally found my problem. it's about binding event to submit-button after it's loaded dynamically. So I used jquery on function:

```
    $("#main").on('click', "#submit-button", function (e) {...  }
```

Because #main is always there and it's not loaded dynamically, this code works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

You are using input button submit and jquery submit together . when you click on submit button then your default submit event is triggering. use `onsubmit="return false;"` in form tag or `e.preventDefault();` in your submit function to prevent default event.

try

```
<form id="mail-form" onsubmit="return false;" name="contactform" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
```

Comment: This isn't right. When the `type=submit` button is clicked it will trigger the submit event on the form and the OP's code already has `e.preventDefault()` in the submit handler.

Comment: Yes that's why I have suggest try `onsubmit="return false;"`

Comment: @nnnnnn Sir I agree your point. as I have written in my answer your can use this or that. when first option is not working. then try another option.

Answer (score 0):

It might occur because DOM is not fully loaded.

Try disabling the button from html:

```
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Send your message" disabled>
```

Wrap jquery events inside, so that they are fired once the DOM is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    //Enable submit button now
    $("#submit-button").removeAttr("disabled");

    //Attach submit handler to form
    $("#mail-form").submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
          $.post("send_form_email.php", $("#mail-form").serialize(), function(data) {
             showThankYou();
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why use a click handler on the submit button? The submit button will cause a submit event on the form, and the OP's code binds a submit handler, so how does that part of your answer help? (You're probably right that the OP is missing the ready handler.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: thanks updated my answer .. hope it sounds clear now

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: it looks like you haven't disabled the button through html.. here are few things 1- Disable the button through html first 2- Move the js(main.js) before closing the body tag right at the bottom of html doc

Answer (score 0):

Since you are apparently loading the javascript from a separate file, you probably include it before the form is defined, which means that it will not bind to the form.

Make sure the wrap the javascript in an

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Your code  
});
```

So that the binding is triggered after the form html is actually loaded.

Comment: i did wrap my js in $(document).ready(function() {
   // Your code  
});

Comment: Okay then that isn't the issue. You just didn't make that clear in your question.